# homeomorphism still isotopic to the identity after the deletion of points.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have a surface $M$ (without boundary) and a homeomorphism 
$f:M \rightarrow M$, which is isotopic to the identity on $M$. If I delete two points $x$ and $f(x)$ from the surface, I get a homeomorphism $$\tilde{f} : M \backslash\{x,f(x)\} \rightarrow M \backslash\{x,f(x)\}$$

by restricting the homeomorphism $f$ to the punctured surface. My question is now:

**Is $\tilde{f}$ also isotopic to the identity on $M \backslash\{x,f(x)\}$?**

Could it be possible to perturb the original isotopy to get the desired new one?

Many thanks!

Comment: The map should be $\tilde{f} : M \backslash\{x,f^{-1}(x)\} \rightarrow M \backslash\{x,f(x)\}$.

Comment: The statement '$\tilde{f}$ is a homeomorphism of the punctured surface' is incorrect because you would need $f(f(x))=x$ in order for the map $f$ to restrict to a homeomorphism of $M\setminus\{x,f(x)\}$.

Comment: Even given this condition that $f(f(x))=x$, we do not get $\tilde{f}$ isotopic to the identity. For instance imagine a homeomorphism $f$ of the plane which rotates the unit disk by $\pi$ radians anticlockwise, and is extended to the rest of the plane in such a way that the plane is fixed 'at infinity'. This map swaps $a=(0,1)$ and $b=(0,-1)$ but on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{a,b\}$ we have $\tilde{f}$ not isotopic to the identity (this generates the so called mapping class group of the twice punctured plane, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: A similar example is a 180 degree rotation of the 2 sphere. Remove  two antipodal points from the equator of the rotation> The map restricted to this punctured sphere is not homotopic to the identity. Similarly the antipodal map restricted to the 3 sphere minus two poles is not homotopic to the identity.